# BIOS Disk - Read Sectors Into Memory (int 0x13, ah=0x02) blocking

Tags: x86, qemu, bootloader, osdev, mbr

I am writing a MBR and using [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) for testing.

When using [read sectors into memory (`int 0x13, ah=0x02`)](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0607.htm), the `int` instruction seems to block execution of my program, and it proceeds to hang. I have tested this with various print statements to confirm that it is this particular instruction blocking.

What could make the interrupt block? I thought this could only be done with the `cli` instruction, and even then it does not block `int` instructions.

---

For context, this is the code leading up to the blocking interrupt in `read_sectors_16`:

```
        [bits 16]        
        [ORG 0x7C00]
        jmp 0x000:start_16      ; ensure cs == 0x0000

        reset_failure_str db 'error: boot disk reset', 13, 10, 0
        read_failure_str db 'error: boot disk read', 13, 10, 0
        boot_segaddr dw 0x7E00

        read_attempt_str db 'read attempt', 13, 10, 0
        end_read_attempt_str db 'end read attempt', 13, 10, 0

start_16:
        ;; Initialize segment registers
        mov ax, cs
        mov ds, ax
        mov es, ax

        jmp load_bootsector_2            


load_bootsector_2:              ; Read program from disk
        ;; dl set by BIOS to the drive number MBR was loaded from
        mov cx, 0x0002          ; cylinder 0, sector 2
        xor dh, dh              ; head 0
        mov al, 0x01            ; load 1 sector
        mov bx, boot_segaddr    ; destination - load right after the boot loader
        call read_sectors_16
        jnc .success
        mov si, read_failure_str
        call print_string_16        
        jmp halt                ; halt

        .success:        
        jmp boot_segaddr:0000   ; jump to program
```

And here is the function with the blocking interrupt:

```
;;; read_sectors_16
;;;
;;; Read sectors from disk in memory using BIOS services
;;;
;;; input:      dl      = drive
;;;             ch      = cylinder[7:0]        
;;;             cl[7:6] = cylinder[9:8]
;;;             dh      = head
;;;             cl[5:0] = sector (1-63)
;;;             es:bx   -> destination
;;;             al      = number of sectors
;;;
;;; output:     cf (0 = success, 1 = failure)
read_sectors_16:
        pusha
        mov di, 0x02            ; set attempts (max attempts - 1)

        .attempt:
        mov ah, 0x02            ; read sectors into memory (int 0x13, ah = 0x02)
        int 0x13                ; TODO: this call is not returning!
        jnc .end                ; exit if read succeeded
        dec di                  ; record attempt
        test di, di
        jz .end                 ; end if no more attempts
        xor ah, ah              ; reset disk (int 0x13, ah = 0x00)
        int 0x13
        jnc .attempt            ; retry if reset succeeded, otherwise exit
        jmp .end

        .end:
        popa
        ret
```

Comment: Have you tried BOCHS instead of qemu?  It has a built-in debugger that lets you examine registers and single step, even in MBR code.  Almost certainly your program isn't literally stuck inside an interrupt handler (unless maybe you passed it bogus args), probably you just have a bug.

Comment: One other thing of interest (not related to your problem, but could be an issue in some environments). `mov ax, cs mov ds, ax mov es, ax` . It is actually possible that _CS_ doesn't have a value of zero. Some BIOSes transfer control to the bootloader with CS=0x07C0: iP=0x0000 which is also physical address 0x07c00. Since you use an _ORG_ of 0x7C00 your code assumes the _DS_ and _ES_ registers will be zero. I'd explicitly set them to zero by doing `xor ax, ax mov ds, ax mov es, ax`. So rather than copy _CS_ to _DS_ and _ES_ we just set DS=ES=0 .

Comment: As well it is probably a good idea to set your own stack SS:SP . The reason being is that you don't know where the BIOS set it and you could inadvertently overwrite it in your own code (ie: read sectors into memory over top of the stack). If you set your own you know exactly where it is and can avoid clobbering it by accident.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing that stands out are your segments. First your code defines `boot_segaddr` as:

```
boot_segaddr dw 0x7E00
```

This creates a 16-bit word in memory with the value 0x7E00. You then have these 2 lines:

```
mov bx, boot_segaddr
[snip]
jmp boot_segaddr:0000
```

In both these cases `boot_segaddr` is being used as an immediate. You are using the address of `boot_segaddr`, not the value `boot_segaddr` points to.

I would alter `boot_segaddr dw 0x7E00` to be a constant value (using `EQU`) and rename it to look like:

```
BOOT_OFFSET EQU 0x7E00
```

You then can modify `mov bx, boot_segaddr` to be:

```
mov bx, BOOT_OFFSET
```

This would have the effect of moving 0x7E00 to *BX*. The call to *Int 13/AH=2* would read the sectors starting at ES:BX = 0x0000:0x7E00 which is what you want.

The next problem is if we reuse the same constant for the *FAR JMP* like this:

```
jmp BOOT_OFFSET:0000
```

This would result in a *FAR JMP* to 0x7E00:0x0000. Unfortunately this is physical address (0x7E00<<4)+0x0000 = 0x7E000 which is not where you want to be jumping. You want to jump to physical address 0x07E00. You really want a *FAR JMP* to 0x07E0:0x0000 which would be physical address (0x07E0<<4)+0x0000 = 0x7E00. To get the *FAR JMP* working properly we can shift `BOOT_OFFSET` right 4 bits. You can change the line to be:

```
jmp (BOOT_OFFSET>>4):0000
```

Making these changes should get your bootloader working. As it was there were 2 bugs in your original code:

- Using the address of your variable rather than the value at that address
- Doing the *FAR JMP* with the wrong segment value.

The apparent hang was likely caused by reading the sector starting at memory address `boot_segaddr` which is in your bootloader. Likely you overwrote all the code in your bootloader making it work erratically when `int 13h` eventually returned.

---

As Peter points out using an emulator like BOCHS and its internal debugger would allow you to single step through 16-bit real mode code. You would have probably discovered these issues.

Comment: Exactly right, and it has fixed my problem. `int` must not return control to my program when it tries to copy to `0x7E000:0x0000` and fails.